# two tables one for posts and other for friends connected to each other how to retrieve posts of friends

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table the first is post where there is `post_by` and `post coloumns` and the second is `connectionstbl` where there is `memberid` and connected with, where `member` is the logged user and `connectedWith` is the friend

How to retrieve the data of post coloumn where `post_by=the connectedwith`

**Query below:**

```
$result=mysql_query("
        select
        social_posts.posted_by,
        social_posts.post as social_posts_post connectionstbl.connectedwith
        from 
        social_posts,connectionstbl
        where
        social_posts.posted_by = connectionstbl.connectedwith
        order by social_posts.p_id desc
");
while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo $row['social_posts_post']."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Executing the query outputs nothing.

Comment: Can u please properly format ur query...

Comment: please formate your query proper and provide proper table structure so we have help you

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma between social_posts_post and connectionstbl.connectedwith. I'm guessing your error_reporting or display_errors configuration parameters are set up to not display errors, otherwise you'd see a warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should use join:

```
SELECT
    p.posted_by, p.post AS social_posts_post, c.connectedwith
FROM social_posts p
JOIN connectionstbl c ON p.posted_by = c.connectedwith
ORDER BY p.p_id DESC
```